# Getting a null byte array in java from JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am calling a native function from java to return a byte[].
The following is a snippet of the JNI code

```
jbyteArray result;  
jbyte *resultType;  
result = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, 1);  
*resultType =7;
(*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, result, 0, 1, resultType);    
return result;
```

This is supposed to create a byte array of length 1 and the value 7 is stored in it. My actual code is supposed to create an array of dynamic length, but am getting the same problem as in this example.

Now coming to my problem -- in java the array am getting returned from JNI is null.
What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prototype for `SetByteArrayRegion()` is:

```
void SetByteArrayRegion(JNIEnv *env, jbyteArray array, jsize start, jsize len, jbyte *buf);
```

The final argument is a memory buffer which `SetByteArrayRegion()` will copy from into the Java array.

You never initialize that buffer.  You are doing:

```
jbyte* resultType;
*resultType = 7;
```

I'm surprised you don't get a core dump, as you're writing a `7` into some random place in memory.  Instead, do this:

```
jbyte theValue;
theValue = 7;
(*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, result, 0, 1, &theValue);
```

More generally,

```
// Have the buffer on the stack, will go away
// automatically when the enclosing scope ends
jbyte resultBuffer[THE_SIZE];
fillTheBuffer(resultBuffer);
(*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, result, 0, THE_SIZE, resultBuffer);
```

or

```
// Have the buffer on the stack, need to
// make sure to deallocate it when you're
// done with it.
jbyte* resultBuffer = new jbyte[THE_SIZE];
fillTheBuffer(resultBuffer);
(*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, result, 0, THE_SIZE, resultBuffer);
delete [] resultBuffer;
```

Comment: Thanks...it works. I tested with the single element array. Guess C isnt really my forte yet. Btw, there was a segmentation fault in my original code , not in this method, but after the GC runs or that array is again passed to JNI for any manipulation